# Unable to send parameters to ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input type="number" maxlength="1" max="5" min="0" placeholder="0" ng-model="rate">
<div ng-init="stars=Func(2)">
  Rating: <span ng-repeat="x in stars track by $index">*</span>
</div>
```

In the above code I want to pass `ng-model="rate"`, **rate** to the function Func.
`ex: Func(rate);` here rate should pass from `ng-model`.

JS Code:

```
var val='';
$scope.Func = function fun(n){
     if(n == 0){ 
        val = val + ''; 
     } else { 
        val = val+'a'; 
        return fun(n-1); 
     } return val; 
};
```

Comment: How about `ng-init="stars=Func(rate)"` ?

Comment: Func(some_number) returns some string. Please tell me how to pass rate to Func from input box.

Comment: So there's a problem with your `Func()`, provide the code and we can help.

Comment: Of course it returns a string, you're *parsing* your values to string.

Comment: Yeah I know and it works fine when I pass a number to Func i.e., Func(2). But instead of 2, I want to pass a number from an input box with ng-model="rate" as Func(rate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to rewrite your `Func`, such that it returns an array that contains the number of elements of your `rate`, so that your `ng-repeat` can use it for the displaying of stars.

It is as easy as

```
  $scope.Func = function(n) {
    return new Array(n);
  }
```

Now, use your `ng-init` to initialize your `rate` to two:

```
<input type="number" maxlength="1" max="5" min="0" placeholder="0" ng-model="rate" ng-init="rate=2" >
```

Plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wz2tYx8gk8XR65OVd4iP?p=preview)

**Edit**: If your requirement is not to use Array aka collection, then `ng-repeat` is out of option. Fear not, we can return a string of stars instead.

Change your `Func` to this:

```
  $scope.getStars = function(n) {

    var stars = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      stars += "*";
    }
    return stars;
  }
```

And your rating will now just display the string:

```
<div >
  Rating: {{getStars(rate)}}
</div>
```

New Plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vdItop0L9aBMW3jGAYzk?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your contribution. But I forgot to tell you a condition that is we shouldn't use arrays

Comment: @CharanCherry right now `ng-repeat` can only work with a collection. If you do not want an array, gotta do some work around

Comment: @CharanCherry added an edit to my answer. Work around provided if you do not want ng-repeat

Comment: Actually i forgot to tell the restrictions. we shouldn't use arrays and must use ng-repeat. Any how I got it exactly what I want. @developer033 3

Comment: In one word: **impossible**. Check its docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat, you **must** have a collection.

Comment: @ developer003 string is also a collection of characters. So in my function I returned a string.

Comment: @CharanCherry, can be a collection of characters, but `ng-repeat` only accept `arrays`.

Comment: If you have any queries just go through my question and follow **CozyAzure's** answer. @developer003

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use arrays and your rate limite is considerably low, you don't need to make a function and you can use [**`ngSwitch`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) to show/hide the appropriate rate, as follows:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.rate = 2;
    })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="number" maxlength="1" max="5" min="0" placeholder="0" ng-model="rate">

  <div ng-switch="rate">
    Rating:
    <span ng-switch-when="1">*</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="2">**</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="3">***</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="4">****</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="5">*****</span>
  </div> 
</body>

</html>
```